# Publishing verification result with tag back to pact Broker with pact-jvm

Tags: pact, pact-jvm

[pact-jvm](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm) can publish the result back to the pact broker. However, I can't seem to find the option or a way to publish with a tag, like in the example of the pact broker:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

This question was already asked on [Github](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/issues/823) and apparently it's now possible with `pact-jvm` in version `4.0.1+`, feature that just came out [yesterday (2019/10/13)](https://github.com/DiUS/pact-jvm/commit/06ab32464d9aaf663c692dc3dab8cad03036f2de):

> ### Tagging the provider before verification results are published [4.0.1+] You can have a tag pushed against the provider version before
>
> the verification results are published. To do this  you need set the
>   `pact.provider.tag` JVM system property to the tag value.